# How to use .loc with groupby and two conditions in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49144154/how-to-use-loc-with-multiple-conditions-and-groupby/49144209#49144209), but I want to expand on this question because I'm asked to do something a little different where I cannot use .duplicates()

I have a df that's grouped by 'Key'. I want to flag any row within a group where the discharge date matches the admit date AND between those rows, the row with the discharge date has a num1 value in the range of 5-12.

```
df =  pd.DataFrame({'Key': ['10003', '10003', '10003', '10003', '10003','10003','10034', '10034'], 
   'Num1': [12,13,13,13,12,13,15,12],
   'Num2': [121,122,122,124,125,126,127,128],
  'admit': [20120506, 20120508, 20121010,20121010,20121010,20121110,20120520,20120520],  'discharge': [20120508, 20120510, 20121012,20121016,20121023,20121111,20120520,20120520]})
df['admit'] = pd.to_datetime(df['admit'], format='%Y%m%d')
df['discharge'] = pd.to_datetime(df['discharge'], format='%Y%m%d')
```

initial df

```
    Key     Num1    Num2    admit       discharge
0   10003   12      121     2012-05-06  2012-05-08
1   10003   13      122     2012-05-08  2012-05-10
2   10003   13      122     2012-10-10  2012-10-12
3   10003   13      124     2012-10-10  2012-10-16
4   10003   12      125     2012-10-10  2012-10-23
5   10003   13      126     2012-11-10  2012-11-11
6   10034   15      127     2012-05-20  2012-05-20
7   10034   12      128     2012-05-20  2012-05-20
```

final df

```
    Key     Num1    Num2    admit       discharge   flag
0   10003   12      121     2012-05-06  2012-05-08  1
1   10003   13      122     2012-05-08  2012-05-10  1
2   10003   13      122     2012-10-10  2012-10-12  0
3   10003   13      124     2012-10-10  2012-10-16  0
4   10003   12      125     2012-10-10  2012-10-23  0
5   10003   13      126     2012-11-10  2012-11-11  0
6   10034   15      127     2012-05-20  2012-05-20  1
7   10034   12      128     2012-05-20  2012-05-20  1
```

I was trying to use filter() but I can't quite figure out how to apply any() to the discharge date. My logic was to pick the first admit date in a group and then check that date among each discharge date and once there is a match then check if the row that has the same discharge date has a value in Num1 in the range of 5-12.

```
num1_range = [5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
df.loc[df.groupby(['Key']).filter(lambda x : (x['admit'] == x['discharge'].any())&(x['Num1'].isin(num1_range).any())),'flag']=1
```

I'm getting an error

```
ValueError: cannot set a Timestamp with a non-timestamp
```

Comment: You may want to split that index expression into several lines and steps; it's near impossible to read, and prone to errors that way. E.g., do you want `x['admit'] == x['discharge'].any()` or `(x['admit'] == x['discharge']).any()`? Probably the latter, because `.any()` makes sense on a series of booleans, not a series of datetime objects.

Comment: change to `df.groupby('Key').filter(lambda x : ((x['admit'] == x['discharge']).any())&(x['Num1'].isin(num1_range).any()))
`

Comment: @Wen this logic doesn't work well with my question. The admit date can equal any discharge date in the group and only the row with the matching discharge date can have a range in num1 from 5-12. Both these rows would then be flagged as 1.

Comment: @martyB by this logic, why is the first row flagged?

Comment: In 2nd row, `2012-05-10` is neither present in the admit date nor the corresponding Num1 is in range 5-12 why is it flagged 1??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you are looking for either of 2 conditions to be satisfied for `flag = True`:

1. Admit date is equal to *any* discharge date within the group (`Key`).
2. Discharge date is equal to *any* admit date within the group, provided `Num1` is in the range 5 to 12 inclusive.

The below logic produces the result in line with your desired output.

**Solution**

```
d1 = df.groupby('Key')['admit'].apply(set).to_dict()
d2 = df.groupby('Key')['discharge'].apply(set).to_dict()

def flagger(row):
    match1, match2 = row['discharge'] in d1[row['Key']], row['admit'] in d2[row['Key']]
    return match2 or (match1 and (row['Num1'] in range(5, 13)))

df['flag'] = df.apply(flagger, axis=1).astype(int)
```

**Result**

```
     Key  Num1  Num2      admit  discharge  flag
0  10003    12   121 2012-05-06 2012-05-08     1
1  10003    13   122 2012-05-08 2012-05-10     1
2  10003    13   122 2012-10-10 2012-10-12     0
3  10003    13   124 2012-10-10 2012-10-16     0
4  10003    12   125 2012-10-10 2012-10-23     0
5  10003    13   126 2012-11-10 2012-11-11     0
6  10034    15   127 2012-05-20 2012-05-20     1
7  10034    12   128 2012-05-20 2012-05-20     1
```

**Explanation**

- Create 2 dictionary mapping Key -> Admit dates and Key -> Discharge dates respectively.
- Use these 2 dictionaries to apply the criteria specified by row using `pd.DataFrame.apply`.

Answer (score 2):

Lets break down the filtration into a few steps. First, create the conditions to be filtered

```
conditions = "(x['discharge'].isin(x['admit'])) & (x['Num1'] >= 5) & (x['Num1'] <= 12)"
```

I Chose to store the `conditions` as string because it looks cleaner for formatting the next step. However, the filter command will be used to check, by `key` in the dataframe, if there are any discharge times equal to admit times. And will also check if `Num1` at the `discharge`time is between 5 and 12. Now we run the `groupby` operation and evaluate `conditions`

```
filter = df.groupby('Key').apply(lambda x: pd.eval(conditions))
filter.index = filter.index.droplevel(0)
```

`filter` will output this

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7     True
dtype: bool
```

`filter` provides some Boolean flags were the `conditions` hold true. The last step is to add the flags for `admit` times equlivant to `dischagre` times which can be done by merging the initial dataframe with the filtered locations which is used to extract the indices of `admit` flags.

```
dex = df.merge(df[filter.values],left_on=['Key','admit'],right_on=['Key','discharge'],how='left').dropna().index
```

Finally set the `flags` where either condition is `True`

```
df['flag'] = (filter | df.index.isin(dex)).astype(int)
```

---

**Full code:**

```
conditions = "(x['discharge'].isin(x['admit'])) & (x['Num1'] >= 5) & (x['Num1'] <= 12)"
filter = df.groupby('Key').apply(lambda x: pd.eval(conditions))
filter.index = filter.index.droplevel(0)
dex = df.merge(df[filter.values],left_on=['Key','admit'],right_on=['Key','discharge'],how='left').dropna().index
df['flag'] = (filter | df.index.isin(dex)).astype(int)
```

**Output:**

```
     Key  Num1  Num2      admit  discharge  flag
0  10003    12   121 2012-05-06 2012-05-08     1
1  10003    13   122 2012-05-08 2012-05-10     1
2  10003    13   122 2012-10-10 2012-10-12     0
3  10003    13   124 2012-10-10 2012-10-16     0
4  10003    12   125 2012-10-10 2012-10-23     0
5  10003    13   126 2012-11-10 2012-11-11     0
6  10034    15   127 2012-05-20 2012-05-20     1
7  10034    12   128 2012-05-20 2012-05-20     1
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:-** 
This solution does not use groupby but uses .loc

I believe that what you want is to set flag as '1' when both admit and discharge day are same and also when the Num1 is between 5 and 12 (inclusive)

Here is the code that works for the logic.

```
df.loc[(df['admit'] == df['discharge'] ) & (df['Num1'].isin(num1_range)), 'flag'] = 1
df.loc[~((df['admit'] == df['discharge'] ) & (df['Num1'].isin(num1_range))), 'flag'] = 0
print(df)
```

The output is:

```
     Key  Num1  Num2      admit  discharge  flag
0  10003    12   121 2012-05-06 2012-05-08   0.0
1  10003    13   122 2012-05-08 2012-05-10   0.0
2  10003    13   122 2012-10-10 2012-10-12   0.0
3  10003    13   124 2012-10-10 2012-10-16   0.0
4  10003    12   125 2012-10-10 2012-10-23   0.0
5  10003    13   126 2012-11-10 2012-11-11   0.0
6  10034    15   127 2012-05-20 2012-05-20   0.0
7  10034    12   128 2012-05-20 2012-05-20   1.0
```

You can see that only the last row satisfies the condition and has flag set as '1'.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the logic correctly, I would write it this way:

```
num1_range = [5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

def get_flags(group):
    flagged_discharge_dates=group.loc[group['Num1'].isin(num1_range),'discharge']
    flag=group['admit'].isin(flagged_discharge_dates)
    flag=flag.astype(int)
    return flag

df['flag']=df.groupby('Key',group_keys=False).apply(get_flags)
df
```

This returns

```
    Key Num1    Num2    admit   discharge   flag
0   10003   12  121 2012-05-06  2012-05-08  0
1   10003   13  122 2012-05-08  2012-05-10  1
2   10003   13  122 2012-10-10  2012-10-12  0
3   10003   13  124 2012-10-10  2012-10-16  0
4   10003   12  125 2012-10-10  2012-10-23  0
5   10003   13  126 2012-11-10  2012-11-11  0
6   10034   15  127 2012-05-20  2012-05-20  1
7   10034   12  128 2012-05-20  2012-05-20  1
```

which I believe is correct according to the logic specified (but differs from the desired outcome in the original post)